# Sub consulta entre duas tabelas mysql, para cada linha um conjunto

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query

É o seguinte tenho uma tabela em mysql na qual guarda o nome dos alunos e nesta mesma tabela tem uma coluna que guarda o código da turma em que o aluno esta matriculado, eu preciso de uma consulta que para cada turma me retorne o conjunto de alunos que pertencem a ela, exemplo

1º ano: -
      joao,
      maria,
      ronaldo,

2º ano: -
      carlos,
      Fabio,
      Marcos,

o problema é que com inner join ela me retorna o nome da turma repetidas vezes
 e para cada posição do array retornado ela me mostra somente um aluno.

exemplo:

1º ano - joao

1º ano - maria

1º ano - ronaldo

2ºano - carlos

2ºano - Fabio

2ºano - Ronaldo

como eu poderia fazer uma consulta que me retorna-se como o primeiro exemplo a cima?

[image: tabela de alunos]

[image: tabela de turmas]

[image: query que estou utilizando]

[image: resultado que estou obtendo]

como podem ver nas imagens o Robert Downey JR esta na mesma turma que o carlos aparecido mas ele aparece em um outro indice do array eu queria que ele aparecesse no mesmo indice que o carlos e que assim a turma  1º ano-primário aparecese somente uma vez

Comment: Edite a parte do código php, remova a imagem e coloque o código.

Comment: Alterei a pergunta acrescentando também uma opção separando o resultado com o php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Separando via query

**Como funciona**

```
SELECT ano, GROUP_CONCAT(nome SEPARATOR ', ') FROM alunos GROUP BY ano;
```

Agrupar por ano utilizando o `GROUP BY` e concatenar o resultado separando por vírgula com a função `GROUP_CONCAT`

**Utilizando a sua query**

```
SELECT T.turma, GROUP_CONCAT(A.nome SEPARATOR ', ') from turmas AS T INNER JOIN AS A on (T.idturma = A.idturma) GROUP BY T.turma;
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/149799/7986223)

## Separando com o php

Você pode continuar com a sua query, mas separando no php da seguinte forma

```
//Array similar ao postado na pergunta, que vem atraves da consulta
$dados[0]['turma'] = '1º ano-primário';
$dados[0]['nome']  = 'Carlos Aparecido';
$dados[1]['turma'] = '1º ano-primário';
$dados[1]['nome']  = 'Robert Downy JR';
$dados[2]['turma'] = '2º ano-primário';
$dados[2]['nome']  = 'Stev Jobs';

$novosDados = [];
foreach($dados as $key => $data){

    //Utilizando o nome da turma como índice, conseguimos separar
    //O array de nomes por turma

    $novosDados[$data['turma']][]  = $data['nome'];
}

echo '<pre>';
var_export($novosDados);
echo '</pre>';
```

> Assim cada índice é uma turma e dentro deste índice há um `array` de nomes

**Resultado**

```
array (
  '1º ano-primário' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Carlos Aparecido',
    1 => 'Robert Downy JR',
  ),
  '2º ano-primário' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Stev Jobs',
  ),
)
```

Comment: acredito que da forma que mostrei ficou meio confuso, sub umas imagens ai da uma olhada, mas ja vlw mesmo assim

Comment: Esta segunda query não deu o resultado esperado por você?